# Azure Notification Hub for Web Applications

Tags: javascript, azure, listener, webhooks, azure-notificationhub

I need to create a Azure Notification Hub which will push notifications to my WebApplication.

The current architecture of Notification Hub just allows applications registered on Windows Dev store to register to Notification Hub using SID's.

Is there a way I can listen to Notifications from a WebApp/Console App

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can listen to Notifications from a WebApp/Console App

In short answer **no**. Push notifications is a form of app-to-user communication where users of **mobile** apps are notified of certain desired information, usually in a pop-up or dialog box.

If want to listen message from other service, I recommand you could use the Azure storage or Azure service bus with Azure function or WebJob
You could get more detail information from [Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview#what-are-push-notifications).